# How to use amp-list if API response itself is the desired array

Tags: amp-html

According to [amybyexample.com](https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-list%2Fsource%2Fhttp://)

> The response must be a JSON object containing
>     an array property `items`

but my API response is array itself, for example:

```
[{"name":"xxx","id":2663755,"category":"sss",},{..},{...}]
```

How can I populate amp-list in this case?

In [ampproject.org](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list) the following point is mentioned about the same

> If the response itself is the desired array, use the value of ".". The expected response is: [...].

but I am not able to figure out how to use this.

Comment: by default the parent term is "items". You have to specify the new parent is "name". If you have an additional tree structure in you JSON, you have to further walk-the-tree by specifying the next term. I would need to see the real JSON to show how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

its simple, just embed your array with "items", its mandatory attribute, as amp-list listens only to this attribute.

Comment: not true. AMP supports alternative JSON structures.

Answer (score -1):

For the first part, what it's basically saying is the all encompassing array must be items. So for your array it would be like this:

```
{"items": [{"name":"xxx","id":2663755,"category":"sss",},{..},{...}]}
```

For populating the amp-list, check out the [Linked Dropdowns](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/linked_dropdowns/) AMP by Example page. That gives a pretty good example of working with amp-list and JSON arrays.

Comment: the OP specified a different JSON structure. OP may not be able to edit the JSON to conform to your (correct) structure.

Comment: Can you please re-read the question again? - that is exactly the structure he wants to avoid.